# android8.0 cann't check fingerpring update,when I add a new fingerprint in my device

Tags: android

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/fingerprintdialog/MainActivity.java

pls see that code(that code is google samples of android fingerprint), I do same as it, but when I add a new fingerpint , this method return true, don't return false. this issue just find in android8.0.

I want to known why.pls help me if you known.

Comment: pls see initCipher(Cipher cipher, String keyName) method in MainActivity.java

Comment: can you please share your manifiest file here?

Comment: please don't give a link to your code, include it here in your post

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link,
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)

> The key will become irreversibly invalidated once the secure lock
>   screen is disabled (reconfigured to None, Swipe or other mode which
>   does not authenticate the user) or when the secure lock screen is
>   forcibly reset (e.g., by a Device Administrator). Additionally, if the
>   key requires that user authentication takes place for every use of the
>   key, it is also irreversibly invalidated once a new fingerprint is
>   enrolled or once no more fingerprints are enrolled, unless
>   setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean) is used to allow validity
>   after enrollment. Attempts to initialize cryptographic operations
>   using such keys will throw KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException.

Comment: Hi Samir,
1,In my AndroidManifest.xml ,I have set the <users-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"

Comment: I also set setUserAuthenticationRequired(ture)

Comment: have you checked this link and my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can get all finger ids as integers:

```
private void getFingerprintInfo(Context context) {
    try {
        FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        Method method = FingerprintManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getEnrolledFingerprints");
        Object obj = method.invoke(fingerprintManager);

        System.out.println("fkie4. CDVBiometricAuthPlugin. obj is null? " + (obj == null));

        if (obj != null) {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.hardware.fingerprint.Fingerprint");
            Method getFingerId = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getFingerId");

            System.out.println("fkie4. CDVBiometricAuthPlugin. obj size: " + ((List) obj).size() + ", getFingerId is null? " + (getFingerId == null));

            for (int i = 0; i < ((List) obj).size(); i++)
            {
                Object item = ((List) obj).get(i);
                if(item != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("fkie4. fingerId: " + getFingerId.invoke(item));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please [refer to this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/fingerprint/Fingerprint.java).

There is a public method `getFingerId()`, but it is not available for us to call because it has `@UnsupportedAppUsage`, so you need to use reflection to call the method. After you get a list of fingerprint ids, you can encrypt them and store them in SharedPreferences.